# Cast anonymous function to a different type using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Say I have this:

```
type T = (x: number) => boolean;

let fn = function(a: string, b: boolean, c: T){};

fn('yes', true, ()=> {

});
```

this won't compile. What I want to do is cast the anonymous function to a certain type, something like this:

```
fn('yes', true, ()=> {

} as T);
```

or

```
fn('yes', true, <T>()=> {

});
```

but that won't compile either, I get this error:

> Cannot find name "as"

How can I cast the function to another type *inline*?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some trial and error, and this apparently is the syntax that works:

```
type T = (x: number) => boolean;

let fn = function(a: string, b: boolean, c: T){};

fn('yes', true, (() => {

}) as any);

fn('yes', true, <any>(() => {

}));
```

seems to require a few extra parenthesis than I expected.